# How to make sure we are both formatting in the same way?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellij-idea, formatting, editorconfig

I'm working on a project with another developer. I am using Visual Studio and he is using Intellij I think. When I push in the code tho, there are always changes in the way the code formats. We have editorconfig and this is all we have in there:

{
"formatOnPaste": false
}

How do I make sure we are both formatting the code in the same way?

Answer (score 1):

Code format is affected by several settings and possibly plugins, per user, per workspace, that may even be overridden by the user.

Prettier does a very good job for most languages: here's a link for VSCode, the same may apply to the full Visual Studio: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/code-formatting-with-prettier-in-visual-studio-code

Put the prettier settings in a .prettierrc and commit that along with your source code.

Git line endings might be another reason why code changes upon committing, especially if you're on different OSes. Here's an accessible explanation to make git consistent: https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/github/using-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings

Hope this puts you in the right direction.